# Sunspot_mongoid rake sunspot:reindex rake aborted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sunspot

Hello Guys I am trying working with sunspot_mongoid but rake not working for me.

I follow the instruction of

https://github.com/aq1018/sunspot_mongoid

I trying working with this command in my console:

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```

the result:

```
rake aborted!

uninitialized constant ActiveRecord

Tasks: TOP => sunspot:reindex
.
.
.
```

When I trying put this code in my index controller:

```
def index
  @search = House.search do
  fulltext params[:search]

  end
  @houses = @search.results
  end
```

I catch the next error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in HousesController#index

Calling Document#find with nil is invalid!
```

Anymore help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Problem Fixed :D. See the https://github.com/balexand/sunspot_mongo/issues/1